# Error configuring logback JMSQueueAppender

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, logback

I have the application that reads the messages from the ActiveMQ queue configured with Spring JMS. It has the following listener:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "loggingQueue", containerFactory = "myJmsContainerFactory")
public void receiveMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + message + ">");
}
```

There is the configuration:

```
@EnableJms
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.logging")
public class LoggingConfig {

private static final String JMS_BROKER_URL = "tcp://localhost:61616";

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(JMS_BROKER_URL);
    return activeMQConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myJmsContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return factory;
}

}
```

The listener works fine, it triggers when the message appears in the loggingQueue.

And I have another, web application deployed on embedded Jetty server that supposed to write logs to that queue using the logback logger:

I have the following configuration for the JMSQueueAppender:

```
<appender name="Queue" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.JMSQueueAppender">
    <InitialContextFactoryName>
        org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
    </InitialContextFactoryName>
    <ProviderURL>tcp://localhost:61616</ProviderURL>
    <QueueConnectionFactoryBindingName>
        ConnectionFactory
    </QueueConnectionFactoryBindingName>
    <QueueBindingName>loggingQueue</QueueBindingName>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Queue" />
</root>
```

That configuration causes the appender to fail when making the jndi lookup for the queue binding name "loggingQueue".

Please, help to configure that appender correctly.

UPDATE:
I've found that the jndi properties with jms configuration are not available using Jetty server.
Maybe there is a way to let Jetty get these properties?

Comment: Have a look at http://mr0ger-arduino.blogspot.com.by/2015/08/logging-asynchronously-with-logback.html , looks like a detailed tutorial